# How to create navigation bar translucent effect?

Tags: swift

I have the table view with headers. Headers have only custom text and white background. Headers are pinned on top when scrolling and I want to know, is there any way how to make the background of headers translucent same as navigation bar is? With some blur effect?
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: post an image of what you want and what have you done so far

Comment: @Lifeplus: Which version and type of OS? iOS x.x, tvOS, ...?

Comment: @Sal iOS 10.0+, testing on newest iOS

Comment: @Reinier Melian Ill attach picture tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Change the backgroundColor to .clear, add a UIVisualEffectView below the label and set the constraints to the edges. Not sure if it will mimic the behaviour of navbar by default so you would have to play around a little with the UIBlurEffect options to get the desired effect.

```
 let blurEffectStyle = UIBlurEffectStyle.extraLight
 let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: blurEffectStyle)
 let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
```

Then add to view and set the constraints

Comment: I agree. Isn't UIBlurEffect given to us _exactly_ so that we can imitate the bar translucency? Hard to see what the OP wants if this isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```